# C# Restricting DLL's to only one instance

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I essentially want to make an api for an application but I only want one instance of that dll to be running at one time.

So multiple applications also need to be able to use the DLL at the same time. As you would expect from a normal api.

However I want it to be the same instance of the dll that the different applications use. This is because of communication with hardware that I don't want to be able to overlap.

Comment: I believe you meant to use a `Singleton pattern` but not one instance of the dll rather having only one instance of a particular object.

Comment: Hi this might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038111/can-a-singleton-class-inside-a-dll-be-shared-across-processes

Comment: Use an event with a name, if the event exists this is not the first instance and fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DLLs are *usually* loaded once per process, so if your application is guaranteed to only be running in single-instance mode, there's nothing else you have to do. Your single application instance will have only one loaded DLL.

Now, if you want to "share" a "single instance" of a DLL across applications, you will inevitably have to resort to a client-server architecture. Your DLL will have to be wrapped in a Windows Service, which would expose an HTTP (or WCF) API.

Comment: How will you address this point *However I want it to be the same instance of the dll that the different applications use*

Comment: @Rahul Oh, I totally missed that point. Thanks, I'll clarify.

Comment: How would the top level applications communicate with the API then?

Comment: @Danielhobby Depending on what you API looks like. If your Windows Service will be exposing a WCF service, Visual Studio (and .NET Framework in generl) has built-in tools. If it is a (REST) HTTP API, you'll need to write a custom client.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that as you intend to do. The best way to do this would be having a single process (a DLL is not a process) which receives and processes messages, and have your multiple clients use an API (this would be your DLL) that just sends messages to this process.

The intercommunication of those two processes (your single process and the clients sending or receiving the messages via your API) could be done in many ways, choose the one that suits you better (basically, any kind of client/server architecture, even if the clients and the server are running on the same hardware)

Answer (score 1):

This is an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type of question. Your actual requirement is serializing interactions with the underlying hardware, so they do not overlap. Perhaps this is what you should explicitly and specifically be asking about.

Your *proposed* solution is to have a DLL that is kind of an OS-*wide* singleton or something like that. This is actually what you are asking about; although it is still not the right approach, in my opinion. The OS is in charge of managing the lifetime of the DLL modules in each process. There are many aspects to this, but for one: most DLL instances are already being shared between every process (mostly code sections, resources and such - data, of course, is not shared by default).

To solve your ***actual problem***, you would have to resort to multi-process synchronization techniques. In Windows, this works mostly through [named kernel objects](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Win32API/WIN32API_Kernel_Objects_Handles_Synchronization.php) like mutexes, semaphores, events and such. Another approach would be to use [IPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx), as other folks have already mentioned in their respective answers, which then again would require in itself some kind of synchronization.

Maybe all this is already handled by that hardware's device driver. What would be the real scenarios in which overlapped interactions with the underlying hardware would have a negative impact on the applications that use your DLL?

Comment: If two applications using the DLL should ask the hardware to perform something at the same or similar time then there would be a confusion of results. I want to avoid this. The solution I thought to do this would be to share the DLL.

Comment: @Danielhobby I think it will be easier to use a system wide, named mutex to synchronize access to the hardware than writing a service.

Comment: @AlexDev I'm struggling to find a good example of a mutex in action. Any ideas where I could look?

Comment: Last time I needed it I found the information scattered around on SO and some other places, and even had to correct it, and in my case ended using an `EventWaitHandle`, since the mutex got abandoned when the thread exited which in my case wasn't good, but in you case I think that's what you need.

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186747/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx. Just remember to use 'Global\' in the name, and watch out for the AbandonedMutexException.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure you have loaded one DLL per machine, you would need to run a controlling assembly in separate AppDomain, then try creating named pipe for remoting (with IpcChannel) and claim hardware resources. [IpcChannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will fail to create second time in the same environment. If you need high performance communication with your hardware, use remoting only for claiming and releasing resource by another assembly used by applications.

Answer (score 0):

Mutex is one of solution for exclusive control of multiple processes.

***But Mutex will sometimes occur dead lock. Be careful if you use.

Comment: I am assuming you mean the same thing as Leandro Taset, but you should make it clearer.